# How to set enableLoggingRequestDetails='true' in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging

I'm trying to debug my app today but the spring boot console displays the following message:

> enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data

Meanwhile, I want to know everything that is going on in the app.

So my question is: How can I enable logging request details in `application.properties`?

Comment: add `spring.http.log-request-details=true` to your `application.properties`. Assuming you are using Spring Boot 2.1 here.

Comment: @M.Deinum you solved it. Please Add you comment as an answer so that i will mark it, that way other people will easily find it. Thank you!

Comment: @AdinduStevens It's working fine, but I don't have any informations about the request... Do you have to configure something else ?

Comment: @Phoste You need to also configure the web logging level to `DEBUG` or any lower level: `logging.level.web: DEBUG`

Answer (score 65, accepted):

For Spring Boot 2.1 and below use

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
spring.http.log-request-details=true
```

For Spring Boot 2.2 and above `spring.http.log-request-details` has been deprecated so use

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
spring.mvc.log-request-details=true
```

in your `application.properties` if you want to see loggingRequestDetails.

From the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html):

> Whether logging of (potentially sensitive) request details at DEBUG
> and TRACE level is allowed.

Comment: one point of clarification for those who didn't catch on quickly (like me):  If you are not using application.properties and using another framework for app configuration, then set these values in your app config.. where ever that may be.

Comment: Property `spring.http.log-request-details` is Deprecated: Use `spring.mvc.log-request-details` instead.

Comment: Note that you need use TRACE instead of DEBUG if you want to the headers to be logged.

Answer (score 11):

When using webflux and spring boot 2.3.0 the following properties can be set to log request details.

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web.server.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter=DEBUG
spring.codec.log-request-details=true
```

Answer (score 3):

for spring boot v2.6.2 you can use this:  `spring.mvc.log-request-details=true` and make sure also you have `logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG`

Comment: This answer is already added as a comment in the accepted answer.

Comment: @AdinduStevens which is wrong. answers should be added in answers, not in comments. comments are always subject to removal.

Answer (score 0):

spring boot version is 2.2.6.RELEASE.This configuration item below helps me solve the problem.
`spring.http.log-request-details=true`

Comment: Thanks. Who would have thought there would be soo many ways?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `WebFlux` turn on the `enableLoggingRequestDetails='true'` you can by adding:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFlux
public class WebFluxConfig implements WebFluxConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureHttpMessageCodecs(ServerCodecConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.defaultCodecs().enableLoggingRequestDetails(true);
    }
}
```

And setting the config param:

```
debug:
  logging.http-requests: true
  
logging:
  level:
    ROOT: INFO
    org:
      springframework:
        web: 
          server:
            adapter:
              HttpWebHandlerAdapter: TRACE
```

Answer (score 0):

With Springboot 3 in order to get request logs from  org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient

Without header just add trace logs of class ExchangeFunctions in application.yml

```
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions: trace
```

Example

```
2023-11-03T13:21:29.907-04:00 TRACE [...] 14608 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.r.f.client.ExchangeFunctions       : [652413fc] HTTP GET https://......, headers={masked}
```

With headers, set log details for codecs in application.yml

```
spring:
  codec:
    log-request-details: true
```

Example

```
2023-11-03T13:39:52.459-04:00 TRACE [...] 5872 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.r.f.client.ExchangeFunctions       : [4a841d85] HTTP GET https://......., headers=[Accept:"application/json", Authorization:"Bearer .....", X-B3-TraceId:"...", X-B3-SpanId:"...", X-B3-ParentSpanId:"...", X-B3-Sampled:"0"]
```